# How to route traffic from VM (Parallels) over an Open VPN connection on the host (OS X)

Tags: virtual-machine, openvpn, routing, ipfw

Scenario:

I have a Mac running Lion that is connected to an OpenVPN server
I have a Windows XP VM (running on parallels, but I don't think this is important)
I want to be able to route traffic from the XP VM via the host Mac's OpenVPN connection so that I can log on to a domain.

The remote network is 172.16.0.0/23 (255.255.254.0)
Open VPN is configured to supply address in the 10.100.101.0/24 range and sets up the routing to 172.16.0.0 using the gateway 10.100.101.1/32
My local network is 192.16.1.0/24

NOTE: I do not want to install OpenVPN into the XP virtual machine as I would have to use a passwordless key in order for OpenVPN to connect before logon.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

So I figured this out (for my needs at least) and it was a lot simpler than I first thought.

Initially I over thought the problem and tried to use bridged networking, making my host the gateway and then attempting to route the traffic to the tun0 adapter - waste of time.

**Solution:**
In the device menu in parallels just set the network to 'shared'.
In the XP (or whatever) VM manually set the DNS to the address of your domain controller (so in my case 172.16.0.254).
Connect to OpenVPN on the Host, I use Tunnelblick to manage this on OS X. OpenVPN should add the correct routes for you.

There is no reason this should not work for VirtualBox or VMWare on Linux or Windows host too.

That is it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Mac OS X, using Parallels 9, and I got this to work by simply selecting "Devices > Network 1 > Shared Network". Nothing else seemed to be required.

*Mac OS X* is version 10.9.2.

*Parallels Desktop 9* (Build 9.0.24229, according "File > About Parallels Desktop").

Answer (score 0):

1. Configure virtual machine
2. Change network source to shared network
3. if that still does not work, disable ipv6 in guest machine.